# В чем уязвимость access в С/C++?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Я находил похожий вопрос на stackoverflow, но я так и не понимаю в чем смысл подмены ?
Вот мы хотим проверить что файл доступен для чтения и если доступен -> открыть. Отлично, мы проверили, файл доступен -> открыли. Другая ситуация: проверяем, доступен ли файл на чтение -> нам его подменяют -> отрываем другой файл(проблема). Чем вторая ситуация отличается от того, что я успею подменить файл в таком коде:

###Псевдокод 1###

```
int main()
{
  delay(5) #delay 5 sec
  open("substitutedFile", "r")
}
```

###Псевдокод 2###

```
int main()
{
  ....
  .... # Slow code, low performance
  open("substitutedFile", "r")
}
```

Вопрос в том, почему уязвимый именно access ? Когда такую подмену можно сделать в любом из выше приведенных сценариев. Зачем вообще нужен access если возвращаемое значение open даст мне знать, доступен ли файл на чтение/запись, а execv в возвращаемом значении даст понять, доступен ли файл на выполнение
https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/sec04/tech/full_papers/dean/dean_html/accessopen.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925177/access-security-hole

Comment: О чём вы вообще?

Comment: Да, может быть, вы добавите какую нибудь поясняющую ссылку о том, что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @S.H. добавил ссылки

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавил ссылки

Comment: По первой ссылке в разделе `2.1 The Problem` же четко расписана проблема.

Comment: Я думаю "уязвимость" - это не правильный перевод. Правильнее сказать опасность использования. Т.е. при использовании access + open можно получить баг.

Answer (score 1):

> Зачем вообще нужен access если возвращаемое значение open даст мне знать, доступен ли файл на чтение/запись, а execv в возвращаемом значении даст понять, доступен ли файл на выполнение

В абсолютном большинстве случаев так и надо поступать: просто пробовать открыть файл и обрабатывать ошибки, если это не удалось (с `exec()` это может быть затруднительно).

Как говорит [тётя маня](http://ru.manpages.org/access/2), `access()` в отличии от `open()` использует не *эффективные*, а *реальные* UID/GID, т.е. их результат может быть разным для процессов с suid битом и именно в таких случаях нужно использовать `access()`:

> Другими словами, `access()` не отвечает на вопрос «могу я прочитать/записать/выполнить  этот  файл?». Он  отвечает  на  немного  другой  вопрос:  «(предположим я исполняемый файл с setuid) может ли **пользователь, запустивший меня** прочитать/записать/выполнить этот файл?», что даёт программам с set-user-ID возможность не дать злонамеренным пользователям прочитать файлы, которые пользователи не должны читать.

#### Когда возникает уязвимость

Допустим есть процесс с suid, который должен проверить, есть ли у вызвавшего его пользователя право на чтение заданного файла:

```
if(access("/path/to/file", R_OK) == 0) {
  int fd = open("/path/to/file", O_RDONLY);
  assert(fd>=0);
  print_file(fd);
  close(fd)
}
```

В этом случае возможна следующая последовательность действий:

- т.к. изначальный файл принадлежал пользователю, то проверка `access()` выполняется успешно.
- Злоумышленник удаляет исходный файл и заменить его ссылкой на файл к которому у него нет доступа, например, ссылкой на `/etc/shadow`.
- т.к. процесс работает с повышенными привилегиями, то вызов `open()` успешно открывает файл по ссылке и выводит его.

`man` в принципе рекомендует «*избегать использования данного системного вызова*».

Comment: Если у "злоумышленника" была возможность запустить процесс, который потом начал работать с повышенными привилегиями, то значит можно считать, что у него и так есть доступ `/etc/shadow`...

Comment: @user7860670, нет, конечно... возможность запуска suid/sgid'ных процессов ни как не связана с возможностью доступа к другим файлам...

Comment: Я думаю "уязвимость" - это неправильный перевод. Правильнее сказать опасность при совмесном использовании с другими функциями. Т.е. при использовании access + open можно получить гарантировано баг.

Comment: @nick_n_a, нум... да, уязвим, конечно, не сам `access()`, а уязвим его конкретный конкретный способ использования, но проблема с самим вызовом в том, что все остальные способы использования лишены практического смысла...

Comment: Из этого следует, что suid-ная программа должна контролировать возможность подмены -- stat/access/open/fstat -- потом сравниваем результаты stat и fstat

Comment: @avp, гмм... не подписался бы, что это будет безопасно, но придумать, как обойти сравнение, скажем, инода+ctime'а на вскидку не могу — разве что может осечка случиться при  какой-нибудь легальной перезаписи файла... и с `exec()`'ом такое скрестить уже не получится (хотя в этом случае, скорей всего, свои куда большие дырки возникают)... в общем ИМХО, как в мане советуют, проще будет сделать `seteuid(getuid())` на время открытия...

Answer (score 0):

> Зачем вообще нужен access если возвращаемое значение open даст мне знать, доступен ли файл на чтение/запись

Как было указано выше, по стандарту access() проверяет права исходя из реальных UID/GID, а результат open() зависит от эффективных.

Т.е. в программах с повышенными или пониженными привилегиями результат может отличаться.

> Вопрос в том, почему уязвимый именно access ?

Сам access() - неуязвим. Но, программы с повышением или понижением привилегий, которые его неправильно используют, могут иметь весьма неопределённое поведение.

В частности, варианты связки access() и open()

> https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/sec04/tech/full_papers/dean/dean_html/accessopen.html
> Fixing Races for Fun and Profit: How to use access(2)

Выглядит корректным.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925177/access-security-hole

Не выглядит полным, в части прав на поиск по пути.

Для однопоточных программ, вероятно, самым надёжным и простым является способ: `... seteuid(); setegid(); open(); ...`